# Append default prefix for all collections in neo4j

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j

I'm using community edition neo4j 4.2.4 in spring boot for implementing region specific collections of all the nodes and relation (max 5 nodes)in the same DB.

Is there a way to append a prefix for all the collections in neo4j, so that I can keep the collection specific to each region?
I can achieve this in
`DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride.withTableNamePrefix(prefix + "_");`
in dynamoDb

Is there any equivalent of this or does it require a data model change to implement this in the community edition of neo4j?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I didn't understood well but can't you just add a specific label for that collection?

Comment: Thanks utnaf for the reply, Let me explain in simple words. Assume I have 5 nodes, I need these 5 node to be specific for each region. say 5 nodes for US and 5 node for EU with US and EU as their prefix. (instead of storing all of them in the same collection and filtering them each time when retrieving)

Comment: I don't think that's a big deal. If you MATCH(n:Node:EU) RETURN n it's basically the same speed as doing MATCH(n:Node). Same reading speed.

Comment: Plus Neo4j doesn't have the concept of "collection". You can use different databases one for each region but I highly discurage  this approach.

Comment: I agree with you, ideally it must be in different databases. since it is not available in the community edition I'm looking for a work around to overcome this limitation. The main concern with the same collection is data isolation and maintainability.

Comment: Maybe I don't have enough informations about your domain, but I really think that differentiating the regions by label would be ok. Think about the a label as a table in the relational world. You'll just have to match the regions from that table. What do you think?